# What is the best way to figure out when an additional instance is about to be needed?

Tags: google-app-engine

On the dashboard, there are many charts that we can look at.

Which one would be the best to use in order to know when an additional instance will be needed to handle additional traffic?

Some possible ways I thought about :

- When the 'Active instances' line is about to get above the current number of 'Billable instances'
- When 'Milliseconds used per second' is about to break over 1000

Would these be true?
Any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine will spin up a new instance (or make an idle instance active) whenever the pending MS (the amount of time a request has been waiting in the queue) has reached the value you specified in the billing settings. Unfortunately, there's currently no graph that corresponds to that.

Comment: Hi and thanks :) Could this be approximately guessed from a currently available chart? (maybe like from the 2 suggestions I mentionned)

Comment: @ibiza The closest you could get is by dividing active instances by milliseconds used per second - this would give you a rough idea of the utilization of your current instances, and thus when a new one will be necessary. You should probably file a feature request asking for a more useful graph. :)